# How to make virtualenvwrapper work in fish shell?

Tags: shell, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper, fish

Is there any way to make `virtualenvwrapper` work in fish shell? 
When trying to run `virtualenvwrapper` commands, like `workon`, I get the following error:

```
fish: Unknown command 'workon'
```

And when I run

```
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

I get a very long error starting with:

```
fish: Expected a command name, got token of type 'Run job in background'. Did you mean 'COMMAND; and COMMAND'? See the help section for the 'and' builtin command by typing 'help and'.

/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh (line 67): if [ "$OS" = "Windows_NT" ] && [ "$MSYSTEM" = "MINGW32" ]
```

and ending with:

```
source: Error while reading file '/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh'
```

Comment: You'll need to rewrite that sh script into fish syntax.

Comment: I see fish is not a supported shell: http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html

Comment: I have seen some people use Python Env Wrapper (also called Invewrapper). Is that the only possible way then?

Comment: does that support fish?

Comment: That doesn't work either. But now, I came across this: [virtualfish](https://github.com/adambrenecki/virtualfish)
It seems to be a replacement for `virtualenvwrapper` in `fish` :)

Answer (score 18):

There are a number of alternatives, but the best approach I've found is https://github.com/adambrenecki/virtualfish

That will give you a `.fish` wrapper around `virtualenv` with all the `virtualenvwrapper` commands you are used to.